# update query not working in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$values = array ("amount_due"=>$_POST['amount_due']); 

$where = "client_code = '".$_POST['client_code']."'";

$db->UpdateQuery ("due_amount", $values, $where);
```

where clause is not working. if i am not using where clause all the rows gets updated and not just one row.

Comment: Oh man. We are wizards but dont know what is UpdateQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Here are possible solutions:

1. Remove unnecessary quotation marks on your

   `$where = "client_code = '".$_POST['client_code']."'";`

   Change it to:

   `$where = "client_code = \".$_POST['client_code'].\"";`

   *quotation marks inside a quotation mark should be backslashed*
2. Change the variable "where" to something else. It's a constant variable (I think)